# Cobertura Instrumentation

Tags: code

The steps that I followed to instrument the Cobertura

```
instrumenting the sources with cobertura
create war and deploy in tomcat
started the tomcat
```

Tomcat is showing errors :

Mar 22, 2012 4:22:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 22, 2012 4:22:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start

When excluding the listener still i am getting the above error.

I did some R & D and I found that classes having the import statement com.XXX.ppl.servcies making the listener fail. When I exclude them the tomcat is working well.

My problem is there are many classes which have the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

i tried instrumentation of class with java  1.7 when i reverted back to java version 1.6 cobertra is working like-champ